# Can I choose which PostgreSQL version is used by barman?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, barman

I installed `barman` on the same server as my production database. Perhaps not a good choice but it is that way. I use `barman` to make backups of the production database and of databases on other servers. Some of those databases are for development.

When there is a new version of PostgreSQL I first migrate the development databases to test the upgrade and some applications. When this is done, I do the production database as the last one.

During this time I want to continue to do backups of all of my databases. This is only possible if `barman` uses the new version. I thought that I could resolve this by installing the new version on the server that runs `barman`. I can see that after the installation that the `psql` used is from that version. But `barman` says that it uses the version from the production database.

Is there a way to tell `barman` which PostgreSQL version it should use?

Answer (score -2):

Isn't this driven by this environment variable? I would believe so.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not answer with an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) when text would work just fine.

Comment: So you point to the Barman manual? I checked it and I will try it for the next upgrade to version 17. Strange that the PG_MAJOR_VERSION is not set to the one of the `psql` executable, and others for PostgreSQL, in the `/usr/bin` directory.